# net5.0" and "net.5.0-windows7.0" aren't compatible

Tags: wpf, grpc, .net-5

My server is. Net5.0, the project DLL that I want to reference is. Net5.0-windows, the reference display is not compatible,. Net5.0 cannot reference. Net5.0-windows, modify the service project to. Net5.0-windows, load correctly, but I don't know whether it is feasible.

I want to know if there is any other way for me to refer to this. Net5.0-windows project DLL if I don't change the target to. Net5.0-windows.

严重性 代码  说明  项目  文件  行   禁止显示状态
错误  NU1201  项目 Events 与 net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) 不兼容。 项目 Events 支持: net5.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)

NETSDK1136  如果使用 Windows 窗体或 WPF，或者引用使用 Windows 窗体或 WPF 的项目或包，则必须将目标平台设置为 Windows (通常通过在 TargetFramework 属性中添加 "-windows")。

Answer (score 7):

One of your project has `net5.0` as main target, and this project has reference to other project that targets `net5.0-windows7.0`. The net5.0 is more general than the specific OS target such as `net5.0-windows7.0`.

The error is correct, because the general target should not have reference to specific target. Therefore you should change the reference order, not the other way around.
Or better according to the error message, it is suggested that you change the project that target `net5.0` to `net5.0-windows7.0` too, so those projects has the same specific targets.

Comment: Is there any other way for me to refer to this. Net5.0-windows project DLL if I don't change the target to. Net5.0-windows?Will changing targets affect  project development？

Comment: changing target from net5.0 to net5.0-windows7.0 will not affect your project development as long as your target OS is still the same, to target windows 7 as suggested in target name.