# Error building Multi-target-project for net5.0 and net5.0-windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-5

for transparency I have to tell that I posted nearly the same question at the github-repo for the net-sdk, because I think it seem to me like a kind of a bug.

I also would like to ask the experts from stackoverflow, because maybe someone know´s an workaround for my problem. So here´s my question:

---

I am trying to build a library which could be used on different plattforms. Most of the code is writen for net5.0 but there are also some gui-elements which require net5.0-windows and the UseWpf-flag.

So my idea was to create a multi-target solution with the following configuration

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;net5.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

and to tag platform specific code with an compiler define, e.g.:

```
#If WINDOWS7_0_OR_GREATER Then
#End If
```

But as soon as I add net5.0 and net5.0-windows to the TargetFramworks I get an error caused by the following lines inside of the file Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets:

```
  <Target Name="_CheckForInvalidWindowsDesktopTargetingConfiguration"
        BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform"
        Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and $([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals($(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV), '5.0')) and ('$(UseWindowsForms)' == 'true' or '$(UseWPF)' == 'true')">
    <NETSdkError Condition="'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' != 'Windows'"
                 ResourceName="WindowsDesktopTargetPlatformMustBeWindows" />
  </Target>
```

This rule always complains about the missing '-windows' in .net5.0 regardless if there is a more spefic net5.0-windows also listed. Removing this rule the project compiles and seems to work.

So my question is:

- Isn't that rule some kind of wrong? Should the compiler not just stop if **none** of the target-framworks has an support for the wpf-flag?
- Deleting those rule localy in my dotnet-folder doesn't seems to be a good solution to me, because of future updates and other devoloping machines. **Isn't there the possibility to suppress or skip that specific rule during the build-process?**

Comment: Your question is having more than one question in one question and inviting more opinions instead of just an answer. Please be specific and focus on your problem, not asking many things in one question.

Comment: The main question is marked bold: "Isn't there the possibility to suppress or skip that specific rule during the build-process?"

Comment: Nobody any idea?

Comment: Hi, can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328796/net5-0-and-net-5-0-windows7-0-arent-compatible) help you?